# Set 'readonly' or 'disabled' attribute for a django-bootstrap5 bootstrap_field

Tags: django-templates, bootstrap-5, django-bootstrap5

I use django-bootstrap5 (https://github.com/zostera/django-bootstrap5) for my application.

However, I was unable to figure out how to set 'readonly' or 'disabled' in a template.

Is it possible to make a Bootstrap field readonly with the following code?

`{% bootstrap_field form.name size="sm" horizontal_label_class="col-sm-4 fw-bold" horizontal_field_class="col-sm-8" layout="horizontal" %}`